# How to address gpio pins

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I'm kind of new to raspberry pi, and I saw a tutorial about making a LED blink. The LED was connected to pin 17, but the tutorial said pin 11. I connected the LED to pin 17, and in the terminal I wrote pin 11 to HIGH, and it came on. Are the gpio pins addressed differently for software/hardware? Where can I get a chart of these correlations?
Very confused. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different GPIO numbering schemes.

You need to ensure that the software you are using is using the numbering scheme you expect.

See https://pinout.xyz/ for the gory details.

The most popular numbering schemes are

- the (physical) expansion header pin number
- the (Broadcom) GPIO number

I use this chart.

```
GPIO       pin  pin    GPIO
3V3         1    2      5V
0/2 (SDA)   3    4      5V
1/3 (SCL)   5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
21/27      13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
           .......
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```

If the GPIO column has a V it indicates the pin is connected to the power rail and not a GPIO.

Where 2 figures are shown separated by a / the first figure is the GPIO number used on the first revision Pi B boards.